# Use gps position of another phone

Tags: gps

We have a paraplegical friend that loves to play pokemon go (one of the few activities that his condition allow him).
Even so, the care that he needs does not allow us to bring him outside.
We would like to allow his phone GPS to lock onto another droid GPS, and so he can "walk" with us around the city, and stay at home where can can be taken care.
I´ve found how to do that with Bluetooth, but we need to do that over internet...
Any clues?